# Point operations on an elliptic curve in a prime field in c

Tags: c, cryptography, geometry

I am trying to write a program to perform point operations on a elliptic curve in a prime field I am using the standard formulaes for point additions and doubling in my code and these operations are performed by functions that are called but I am getting output for certain points but not all so please help me to fix the problem that are present in this code.

```
structure point_multiply(int x, int y, int k )
{
int xk;
int yk,m;
xk=x;
yk=y;
m=1;
int xL,yL,s,e;
e=findInverse((2*yk),211);
if((((3*(xk*xk))*e)% 211)>0)
{s = (((3*(xk*xk))*e)% 211);

}
else
    s=(((3*(xk*xk))*e)% 211)+ 211;
if((((s*s)- (2*xk)) % 211)>0)
{xL=(((s*s)- (2*xk)) % 211);
}
        else
        xL=(((s*s)- (2*xk)) % 211) + 211;
        if(((-yk+ s*(xk-xL)) % 211) > 0)
        yL=(-yk+ s*(xk-xL)) % 211;
        else
        yL=(-yk+ s*(xk-xL)) % 211 + 211;
        xk=xL;
        yk=yL;
        m=m+1;

while(k>m)
{
    sn=point_addition(xk,yk,x,y);
    xk=sn.a;
    yk=sn.b;
    m++;


}
s1.a=xk;
s1.b=yk;
return s1;
```

}

```
structure point_addition(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
int s,xL,yL;
if((x1-x2)!=0)
{
    if ( x1 == 0 && y1 == 0 )
    {
        xL = x2;
        yL = y2;
        s7.a=xL;
        s7.b=yL;
        return s7;
    }
    if ( x2 == 0 && y2 == 0 )
    {
        xL = x1;
        yL = y1;
        s7.a=xL;
        s7.b=yL;
        return s7;
    }
    if ( y1 == -y2 )
    {
        xL = yL = 0;
        s7.a=xL;
        s7.b=yL;
        return s7;
    }
    l=findInverse((x1-x2),211);
    if ((((y1-y2)*l) % 211)>=0)
          s=((((y1-y2)*l) % 211));
    else
          s=(((y1-y2)*l) % 211) + 211;
    if ((((s*s)-(x1+x2)) % 211)>0)
          xL= (((s*s)-(x1+x2)) % 211) ;
    else
          xL= (((s*s)-(x1+x2)) % 211) + 211;
    if(((-y1+s*(x1-xL)))>=0)
          yL= ((-y1+s*(x1-xL)) % 211);
    else
          yL= ((-y1+s*(x1-xL)) % 211) + 211;
}
else

{
    xL= 0 ;
    yL= 0;

}

s7.a= xL;
s7.b= yL;

return s7 ;
```

}

```
int findInverse(int a, int b)
{
 int x[3];
 int y[3];
 int quotient  = a / b;
 int remainder = a % b;
 x[0] = 0;
 y[0] = 1;
 x[1] = 1;
 y[1] = quotient * -1;
 int i = 2;
 for (; (b % (a%b)) != 0; i++)
 {
  a = b;
  b = remainder;
  quotient = a / b;
  remainder = a % b;
  x[i % 3] = (quotient * -1 * x[(i - 1) % 3]) + x[(i - 2) % 3];
  y[i % 3] = (quotient * -1 * y[(i - 1) % 3]) + y[(i - 2) % 3];
 }

 //x[i — 1 % 3] is inverse of a
 //y[i — 1 % 3] is inverse of b
 if(x[(i - 1) % 3]<0)
return x[(i - 1) % 3]+211;
 else
 //x[i — 1 % 3] is inverse of a
 //y[i — 1 % 3] is inverse of b
 return x[(i - 1) % 3];
  }
```

Edited and added main  c code which uses these function to perform elliptic curve cryptography

```
int main()
{
int y,z=0,x=2,i[200],j[200],h=0,g,k;
    while(x<200)
    {
        y=sqrt((x*x*x)-4);
        z=modulo(y,211);
        if(z!=0)
        {
            i[h]=x;
            j[h]=z;
            s[h].a=i[h];
            s[h].b=j[h];
            s[h+1].a=i[h];
            s[h+1].b=(211 - j[h]);
            printf("\nh=%d X= %d Y= %d \nh=%d X= %d Y= %d",h,s[h].a,s[h].b,h+1,s[h+1].a,s[h+1].b);
            h=h+2;
        }
        x++;

    }
    printf("The total no of points we have on our elliptic curve for cryptography is %d",h-1);
    x=5;
    y=11;
    printf("\n %d %d\n",x,y );
    printf("\nEnter A number between 0 and   the private key");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    s2=point_multiply(x,y,k);
   printf("\n The public key is \n %d %d \n  ",s2.a,s2.b );
   printf("Enter a RANDOM number to generate the cipher texts");
scanf("\n%d",&g);
s3= point_multiply(x,y,g);
s4=point_multiply(s2.a,s2.b,g );
label:
printf("\n Enter a number to send");
scanf("%d",&h);
s6=point_addition(s4.a,s4.b,s[h].a,s[h].b);
printf("The points to be sent are X= %d Y=%d",s[h].a,s[h].b);
printf(" \n X= %d Y=%d\n X = %d Y= %d ",s3.a,s3.b,s6.a,s6.b);
//RECIEVER
s8=point_multiply(s3.a,s3.b,k);
s9=point_addition((s8.a) ,-((s8.b)%211),s6.a,s6.b);
printf(" The decrypted points are \n %d %d",s9.a,s9.b);
        printf("\n If you have more no to send press 1 else press 0");
        scanf("\n %d", &x1);
        if(x1==1)
            goto label;
        else
            return 0;
```

}

s1, s2, s3 etc are structures which hold a 2 integers which act as x and y co-ordinates 
I am getting output by entering k=3,g=4, h=5 and many other cases mostly with small numbers but not for larger numbers. What could be wrong with the code?

Further edit: I guess that normal square root method is not applicable to find square roots of a modular no?.. Please tell me how to find the modular square root of a no?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the input, what are the outputs, what are the expected outputs? Have you tried debugging? Could you get an idea of where the bug could be?

Comment: Also, you are saying you are getting output only for _certain_ points. Do you mean you are getting wrong output for other points or no output at all? If no output, then the problem is with the input/output management maybe?

Comment: That code is nearly unreadable.

Comment: @Shahbaz. The expected ouputs are that the points to be sent and decrypted as shown in the output window should be the same.. I think that for larger numbers somewhere in the program it is going out of bounds for int

Comment: @GregS. Edited the post and added more details

Comment: Please use proper indentation.

Comment: @Shahbaz.. Found out what could be the problem and edited the post.. Please help me to solve the problem..

Comment: @JowinSathianesan, `sqrt` won't do modular square root for you. I actually didn't know about that, but [here](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Modular_Square_Root) there seems to be some information. You could try asking a question on how to find modular square root in http://math.stackexchange.com